# Compile CoffeeScript with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there a way to compile CoffeeScript to JavaScript code using JavaScript? 
User writes CoffeeScript code to a textarea (or a codemirror editor..), and I want to compile the coffee code to js and execute it.

I know how to compile coffee to js with php, or other server side languages but I want to do it  on client side.

Comment: There is a coffeescript compiler in coffeescript and coffeescript compiles to javascript, you can just compile that and use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to [the CoffeeScript site](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and read the "text/coffeescript Script Tags" paragraph.

> In fact, the little bit of glue script that runs "Try CoffeeScript" above, as well as the jQuery for the menu, is implemented in just this way. View source and look at the bottom of the page to see the example. Including the script also gives you access to CoffeeScript.compile() so you can pop open Firebug and try compiling some strings.

Don't forget the `bare` option, or else the compiled code will be wrapped

```
CoffeeScript.compile('alert "hello"', { bare: 'on' })
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://js2coffee.org/) project called js2coffee looks exactly what you need

Comment: Tamas wants to go from CS to JS not the other way.

Comment: @LarryMaccherone, look at the tabs above on the page, there is double option for both of ways

Comment: isn't the CS to JS way the same as using the CS transpiler?